# How can I programmatically create a Firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to create a Firebase project in my account without having to do it through the console?  Can I do it with an API?  I didn't see anything about it in the docs.

I want to use Firebase for my SaaS project, but I use Firebase for authentication.  I don't want to keep all the users in one project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>This is not currently possible. I'd encourage you to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with a detailed use case.</strike>

For what it's worth, it most likely will never be possible to spin up a project for each customer of a SaaS product (unless customers are in the 10s).

The [Firebase Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/) launched at the Firebase Developer Summit in October 2018, and can be used to (among other things) create Firease projects by adding Firebase to existing Google Cloud Platform projects.

Comment: Thanks, I will file.  So what did you mean by "10s"?

Comment: As in fewer than 100 total customers "tens" not "hundreds". Firebase projects are definitely not intended for mass creation.

Comment: This is now possible through the [Firebase Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/).