# How to create project in a firebase and download google-services.json file by command line

Tags: firebase, command

How to create project in a firebase and download .json file by command line

Comment: There is currently no public API, nor a CLI command, a to create Firebase projects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797334/is-possible-create-new-firebase-project-by-api and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147647/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-firebase-project

Comment: Please specify in details your question.

Answer (score -1):

Everything with the command line is found here:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools;
firebase-tools --help;
```